# Стандартный ли тип C#

Tags: c#, .net

Есть 2 класса, разные по названию, но с одинаковыми полями. Для переноса данных из одного класса в другой написал метод:

```
    public object UpdateValues(object a_fromObject, object a_toObject)
    {
        Type _fromType = a_fromObject.GetType();
        Type _toType = a_toObject.GetType();

        FieldInfo[] _fromFields = _fromType.GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo _fromField in _fromFields)
        {
            FieldInfo _toField = _toType.GetField(_fromField.Name);
            _toField.SetValue(a_toObject, _fromField.GetValue(a_fromObject));
        }
        return a_toObject;
    }
```

Всё бы хорошо, но если попадается нестандартный тип, т.е. к примеру еще один класс, то необходимо рекурсивно вызвать метод, к примеру так:

```
    object _fromFieldObject = _fromField.GetValue(a_fromObject);
    object _toFieldObject = _toField.GetValue(a_toObject);
    _toField.SetValue(a_toObject, UpdateValues(_fromFieldObject, _toFieldObject));
```

**Вопрос:** Как лучше определить стандартный тип или производный?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем изобретать велосипед для отображения одного типа на другой? "Все" уже придумано. Существуют десятки стабильноработающих мапперов.
Мы на работе используем [EmitMapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/). Просто и удобно. Советую.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую )

Comment: Удобнее всего брать nuget-пакет отсюда http://nuget.org/packages/EmitMapper

PS да, советую использовать nuget.